# Too many requests from your IP

Tags: help

We are getting the following error message: "Too many requests from your IP, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com.".

We are making the getBlock method calls, with 4 seconds sleeps between requests.

As per the rate limits, we should be within the bounds.

Are there any other rate limits aside from the listed on the official site?

```
Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP: 100
Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP for a single RPC: 40
Maximum concurrent connections per IP: 40
Maximum connection rate per 10 seconds per IP: 40
Maximum amount of data per 30 second: 100 MB
```

Comment: Try different rpc provider. Alchemy, helius are pretty good

Comment: Voting to close this, because Id say the people you need to ask are your RPC provider who will have all the info needed to help you.